# How to combine flexible html panel content with horizontal carousel in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've got some HTML content that is longer than a full page in height. At the end of this content, I'd like to include a horizontal carousel. Every attempt I make shows the HTML content, but I can't get the carousel to work properly.

Here's where I'm at code-wise...

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    fullscreen: true,
    scrollable: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: '<h1>Lots of content</h1><p>With additional content</p><p>With additional content</p><ul><li>asdf</li><li>asdf</li></ul>',
            style: 'background-color: #2E99FC'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'carousel',
            items: [
                {
                    html : 'Item 1',
                    style: 'background-color: #5E99CC'
                },
                {
                    html : 'Item 2',
                    style: 'background-color: #759E60'
                },
                {
                    html : 'Item 3',
                    style: 'background-color: #FF0000'
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have expirience with Sencha 1.1. I have no idea if your syntax is for 1.1 or 2.
i played a little with your code, and here it goes.

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function() {
        var panel= new Ext.Panel({
            html: '<h1>Lots of content</h1><p>With additional content</p><p>With additional content</p><ul><li>asdf</li><li>asdf</li></ul>',
            style: 'background-color: #2E99FC'
        });

        var carousel = new Ext.Carousel({
            flex:1,
            items: [
                {
                    html : 'Item 1',
                    style: 'background-color: #5E99CC'
                },
                {
                    html : 'Item 2',
                    style: 'background-color: #759E60'
                },
                {
                    html : 'Item 3',
                    style: 'background-color: #FF0000'
                }
            ]
        });

        new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [panel, carousel]
        });
    }
});
```

The big thing that was missing to you is the flex:1 property. This is why it didin't appear in your screen. Its highly crucial.

Comment: Thanks -- but if the amount of html content in the panel is larger (longer), I want to be able to scroll down to see the carousel, then be able to use the carousel. With the code above, the carousel just gets rolled off the bottom of the page with increased panel content.